# dwm.exe error debugging in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-8, dwm

I m facing an error while working . It shows a message "dwm.exe" has stopped working . and it is debugging in visual studio . it occurs  if i have stopped moving mouse

[image]

Comment: create a dump and share it: http://pastebin.com/4rNhzBdL

Comment: i have created a dump file but it is an exe file how can i share it Plz help i am newbie ....

Comment: upload the dmp to a cloud service like OneDrie and post a link here.

Comment: have you uploaded the DMP file?

Comment: @magicandre1981  sory i was goring to upload DMP file ...but i have some urgent business so i installed my windows again ..

Comment: and now the issue is gone?

Comment: @magicandre1981 yes it is solved now......

Answer (score 0):

Go to the following registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AeDebug
```

Add a `REG_DWORD` value to the `AutoExclusionList` subkey, where the name is the name of the executable file and the value is 1. By default, the Desktop Window Manager (Dwm.exe) is excluded from automatic debugging because otherwise a system deadlock can occur if Dwm.exe stops responding (the user cannot see the interface displayed by the debugger because Dwm.exe isn't responding, and Dwm.exe cannot terminate because it is held by the debugger).
Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP: The `AutoExclusionList` subkey is not available; thus you cannot exclude any application, including Dwm.exe, from automatic debugging.
The default AeDebug registry entries can be represented as follows:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
   SOFTWARE
      Microsoft
         Windows NT
            CurrentVersion
               AeDebug
                  Auto = 1
                  AutoExclusionList
                     DWM.exe = 1
```